# How do you read user environment variables with ASP.NET Core 2.1 in the ConfigureServices method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, environment-variables, asp.net-core-webapi

I am currently spinning up an ASP.NET Core Web API (version 2.1) and am trying to read custom environment variables that I have set from my local machine. The environment variables I have set are for the AWS client ids, secrets, etc. I am trying to access these environment variables' values within the ConfigureServices method inside the Startup.cs class. However, the following returns 'null', no matter what I try.

```
var result = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("<ENV_VARIABLE>");
```

In order to provide more backgruond, I need to read some client ids and secrets and pass them to the relevant class' constructor. Now, in order to follow best practices, I am not including these IDs and secrets inside the appsettings.json file. Instead, I modified the ~./bash_profile file on my Mac and wrote the following:

```
# Set the General AWS Variables
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<>
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<>

# Set the AWS Cognito Variables
export COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID=<>
export COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID=<>
export COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET=<>
```

I also verified that these environment variables persisted by running

```
printenv
```

Then, I made the ConfigureServices method inside the Startup.cs class look like the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    // The following 3 variables are null
    var userPoolId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID");
    var userPoolClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID");
    var userPoolClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET");

    var amazonCognitoIdentityProvider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
    var cognitoUserPool = new CognitoUserPool(userPoolId, userPoolClientId, amazonCognitoIdentityProvider, userPoolClientSecret);

    services.AddSingleton<IAmazonCognitoIdentityProvider>(x => amazonCognitoIdentityProvider);
    services.AddSingleton<CognitoUserPool>(x => cognitoUserPool);

    services.AddCognitoIdentity();
}
```

However, everytime, the return value of "Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(...)" is 'null'. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. I assume that I have a misunderstanding of environment variables and/or how ASP.NET Core retrieves them but I would greatly appreciate some help as to why my current code does not read the environment variables.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I should also mention that I am trying to do this on a Mac. I'm not sure if that changes the approach on how to retrieve an environment variable, but I just want to mention it here in case it does!

Comment: Under what user you are running process of asp core?

Comment: Look at https://forums.asp.net/t/2158031.aspx?System+Environment+GetEnvironmentVariable+always+return+null

Comment: I mean EnvironmentVariableTarget as second parameter

Comment: @Oleg I was hoping that using the correct EnvironmentVariableTarget would solve the problem; however, it unfortunately did not. I changed to code to try all three options (EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process and EnvironmentVariableTarget.User), but each of them still returned null.

Comment: I should mention that I am on a Mac. Does that affect this at all?

Comment: try `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()` to get all the variables and check if you can see the one you want, maybe there's a prefix

Comment: @Kahbazi I tried doing that and the output of that function does not contain any of these environment variables.

Comment: Have you check the `On macOS and Linux systems` section on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariables?view=netcore-2.1

Comment: @Kahbazi wow okay I think I see the issue. In that link, it states the following:

".NET Core running on Unix-based systems does not support per-machine or per-user environment variables."

That seems to indicate to me that if I don't pass in environment variables through the dotnet run command, it will not read my custom environment variables within ~/.bash_profile. Thank you for sending that link. I think this cleared it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after reading the link Kahbazi sent, I found out the following regarding environment variables and .net core:

".NET Core running on Unix-based systems does not support per-machine or per-user environment variables."

Essentially what this seems to indicate is that I cannot access the environment variables inside my ~/.bash_profile file because .NET Core does not support that. The way I can get around that is by starting the app using the dotnet run command or passing environment variables through docker.

Thank you for the help everyone!

Answer (score -1):

Here is some code I use to get `.bash_profile` environment variables on a **Windows** machine.

```
public static class Utils
{

  public static List<string> ExecuteCommand(string command)
  {
    int exitCode;
    List<string> result = new();
    Process proc = new();

    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \". ~/.bashrc > /dev/null;" + command + " \"";
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    try
    {
      proc.Start();
      while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
      {
        var line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
          result.Add(line);
      }
      while (!proc.StandardError.EndOfStream)
      {
        var line = proc.StandardError.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
          result.Add(line);
      }
      proc.WaitForExit();
      exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      exitCode = e.HResult;
    }

    proc.Close();
    proc.Dispose();
    return result;
  }

  public static string GetVariable(string name)
  {
    return ExecuteCommand($"echo ${name}").FirstOrDefault(string.Empty);
  }

}
```

Comment: This assumes the user has Git Bash installed (and installed in that location), it executes an arbitrary command (do you intend to call it with `printenv`?), it conflates standard output with standard error (what if something failed? This'll interpret that as legitimate output) and finally this doesn't appear to do at all what was asked?

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. I put it here to give people some ideas. It works on my setup. Should I mention that?

Answer (score -2):

Modify your startup.cs file. AddEnvironmentVariables() method should add to config.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                    {
                        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                    })
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Now you can use

```
var userPoolId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID");
var userPoolClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID");
var userPoolClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET");
```

from your configure.cs file.

for additional information, you can browse use these links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1
http://michaco.net/blog/EnvironmentVariablesAndConfigurationInASPNETCoreApps

Thanks

Comment: AddEnvironmentVariables is already done by default so adding it is redundant. It also does not affect Environment.GetEnvVar(), it adds env vars to IConfiguration.